# how github topic feature implemented in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, github

[image]

i wonder how can it show a list of result after the input, and after click the list result, it display on the input text, and can use with mutiple topic.

Are there any js library could implement this easily?
can anybody show some code sample to implement such feature?

Comment: Please find [this demo](http://dbrekalo.github.io/fastselect/) or find **multiselect with tags input** for more plugins

Answer (score 1):

Try this: https://select2.github.io/examples.html#multiple

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(".js-example-basic-multiple").select2();
</script>

<select class="js-example-basic-multiple" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    ...
  <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
```